# Priority Encoder for PWM Signals

Tags: digital-logic, analog, pwm, comparator

I'm trying to command a DC motor and servo of an RC Car with two signals, one from the remote and one from a Raspberry Pi.

I have figured out I need a priority encoder, but there are issues when trying to prioritize a PWM signal.

I was thinking of adding an analog to digital converter for the PWM signal. Then a comparator and reference voltage to determine if a signal is on or off. Then the (clean) binary output of the comparators will be sent to the priority encoder to determine which signal to accept for control.

Hopefully this made sense. Does it seem like I am on the right track?

Comment: Sounds to me like a job for a small microcontroller with 3 timers. 2 to measure the duty-cycle of the incoming PWMs and one to generate the 'prioritized' output.

Comment: Sam, write a lot more. What's the PWM frequencies involved? Are the frequencies different from each other? Or quite similar? How long may the prioritized PWM become inactive before you'd enable the alternate one? (There has to be some time allowed to recognize that it has become inactive. And during that time, the alternate will be ignored. You have to decide if that's okay. If not, there are other problems to wrestle down.)

Comment: @periblepsis If I assume the duty cycle for both is 20ms, then the prioritized PWM should be inactive for at least 20 ms, because this is the "down time" required to recognize if the prioritized PWM is off. 

If a MCU with 3 timers is used, I can see if 20ms has passed since the last signal on the priority PWM. If the priority PWM has a slower duty cycle than the alternative, (say 30ms vs. 20ms) then 30ms needs to be the "down time" to recognize inactivity to look back at the alternate.

Comment: @brhans 
Are priority encoders more useful for signals that are already digital?

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- What kind of PWM are you talking about? There is the common RC signal, 1ms to 2ms pulse width every 20ms. And then there is a PWM signal in the range 0% to 100% at commonly high frequencies (several kHz) to control DC motors (non-brush-less). If you mean the former, how would you like to prioritize? Please [edit] your question and provide for example a decision table. -- Converting to analog and back seems like a bad idea to me, BTW...

Comment: @Sam @ thebusybee mentions two kinds of PWM. (I recall the 20 ms period you mention, but I know nothing about the DC motor PWM mentioned by the busybee.) So that by itself means you need to clarify what's going on. Note that you wrote: *"command a DC motor"*. That sounds more like what @ thebusybee added and where I'm completely ignorant. But you also might be talking about the more common servo pulse, which I do know a little about. As far as prioritizing, there needs to be separate circuits monitoring all of the PWM inputs, providing a go/no-go. These can be prioritized, then.

Comment: @Sam `If I assume the duty cycle for both is 20ms` ... duty cycle is expressed as a percentage, not as a time interval

Comment: Just an extension, the common RC signal is rarely viewed as a PWM signal, and I think it is an error to call it so. Instead, it is an analogously encoded value: the length of the pulse designates the requested servo position or motor power or whatever the value controls. The repetition period is independent of the pulse length, does not mean anything to the encoded value, and early radio controls (think of the 70s of the last century) had different periods.

Comment: @thebusybee I think your separation of ideas is a good one. I suppose it could be considered a required periodic duty cycle in the range of 5% to 10%. But that is a little off-putting and as you also write the period itself should probably be treated as a separate idea, rather than conflating all this into a single PWM idea. Nice note to add!

Comment: What if both signals are present? Should one signal source be dominant?